# Keep original array of elements when using .remove()

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of delete button elements:

```
const DELETE_BUTTONS = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-button');
```

These delete buttons are in a table, and each of them are inside a table row in its own `td`. I add an event listener to it in three different ways.

1. To already rendered delete buttons:

   ```
   for (let x = 0; x < DELETE_BUTTONS.length; x++) {
       DELETE_BUTTONS[x].onclick = function () {
           deleteProperty(DELETE_BUTTONS[x]);
       };
   }
   ```
2. To a new row in the table, which is an inline-form that I add with another `onclick`:

   ```
   ...
   CLONED.classList.add('cloned', 'properties__row');
   const DELETE_BUTTON = CLONED.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;
   DELETE_BUTTON.onclick = function () {
       deleteProperty(DELETE_BUTTON);
   };
   ```
3. When the user has submitted the inline form, I get the data back with Ajax, and create a new `tr` and append it to the table body. (To create this element easily I use another JS function. Note that I did not include the bit where I create the `tr` itself, it is irrelevant.)

   ```
   MAKE_ELEMENT('a', {onclick: 'deleteProperty(this)', class: ['btn-flat', 'waves-effect', 'btn-floating']},
       MAKE_ELEMENT('i', ['material-icons', 'red-text'],
           'delete_forever'
       )
   )
   ```

This is the function that is added with the `onclick`:

```
function deleteProperty(element) {
    element.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

This works perfectly, right up until I delete a second element. Every time I delete an element, it also removes it from the array. Meaning that `deleteProperty(DELETE_BUTTONS[19])` will delete/remove a different element than it did at first. How can I prevent the array from changing length?

I tried to make a copy of the array, but it behaved exactly like the original. I could also just insert an empty place holder in the array when I remove an element so it stays the same length, but this doesn't seem like good practice. Any pointers would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Eat more snacks!

Comment: @connexo Tried that already, didn't work

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) is always useful. In this case it says, that `gEBCN` returns a live HTMLCollection

Comment: use `var newArray = oldArray.slice();` for creating copy of array. This will clones the array and returns the reference to the new array. ...... when you do `newArray = oldArray` both vars points to same array

Comment: @Teemu Yes I didn't take that in account originally when taking this approach. But I don't know of any alternative

Comment: [`document/element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns a static `NodeList`, that would do?

Comment: @Teemu I always thought that querySelector returned a live/dynamic list as well. This is exactly what I need! If you post this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Well, it's also possible to pass the event object to the click handler, and call `deleteProperty(event.target);` instead of using a node list ...

Comment: @Kenny that would work only when the array to clone will contain primitive values only, references (like references to HTML elements) are still copied "by refrence" and are not cloned. Notice also, that `DELETE_BUTTONS` in the snippet is not an array, it doesn't have `slice` method.